# Perl count frequency of keys in hash

Tags: string, perl, frequency

I have extracted the first level of keys from multidimensional hash, which look like:

```
my @string = keys %hash;

print "@string\n";

Bacteroides fragilis (strain YCH46).Agrocybe aegerita (Black poplar mushroom) (Agaricus 
aegerita).Parabacteroides distasonis (strain ATCC 8503 / DSM 20701 / CIP 104284 / JCM 5825 / NCTC 
11152).Pelodictyon phaeoclathratiforme (strain DSM 5477 / BU-1).Clostridium kluyveri (strain NBRC 
12016).Torpedo marmorata (Marbled electric ray).Aethionema grandiflorum (Persian stone-cress).Conus 
consors (Singed cone).Saguinus labiatus (Red-chested mustached tamarin).Staphylococcus haemolyticus 
(strain JCSC1435).Aeromonas salmonicida (strain A449).Acinetobacter genomosp. 13.Staphylococcus 
aureus (strain USA300 / TCH1516).Loxosceles variegata (Recluse spider). and so on...
```

I am trying to count how many times a same organism is repeated (I know for sure that some of there are repeated many times).

I have tried this code:

```
my %count;

foreach my $os (@string)  
{ 
$count{$os}++; 
} 


foreach my $os (sort keys %count)  
{ 
print $os, " ", $count{$os}, "\n";
}
```

But I obtain the output like all of the organisms where just appearing once, although I know that is not the case.

Strangely, when I tried to define a test string manually with some organisms repeated, the code worked.

What is happening with my hash keys?

I am able to access them separately within the list so they are well defined in principle...

Any help?

Edited:

Dumper structure when organism are values:

```
'ACYP_SYNJB' => {
                        '94' => 'Synechococcus sp. (strain JA-2-3B\'a(2-13)) 
(Cyanobacteria bacterium Yellowstone B-Prime).'
                      },
      'ACTM_STRPU' => {
                        '374' => 'Strongylocentrotus purpuratus (Purple sea 
urchin).'
                      },
      'A2ML1_HUMAN' => {
                         '1454' => 'Homo sapiens (Human).'
                       },
      'ACTP_SALDC' => {
                        '549' => 'Salmonella dublin (strain CT_02021853).'
                      },
      'ACBG2_XENLA' => {
                         '739' => 'Xenopus laevis (African clawed frog).'
                       },
      'ACO1_AJECA' => {
                        '476' => 'Ajellomyces capsulatus (Darling\'s disease 
fungus) (Histoplasma capsulatum).'
                      },
      'ACTM_PISOC' => {
                        '376' => 'Pisaster ochraceus (Ochre sea star) 
(Asterias ochracea).'
                      },
      '3MGH_RHOPB' => {
                        '200' => 'Rhodopseudomonas palustris (strain 
BisB18).'
                      }
    };
```

And when keys:

```
$VAR3585 = 'Geobacter sulfurreducens (strain ATCC 51573 / DSM 12127 / PCA).';
$VAR3586 = {
         'ACPS_GEOSL' => 126,
         'ACP_GEOSL' => 77,
         'ACKA_GEOSL' => 421,
         'ACYP_GEOSL' => 91,
         'ACCA_GEOSL' => 319
       };
$VAR3587 = 'Bactrocera dorsalis (Oriental fruit fly) (Dacus dorsalis).';
$VAR3588 = {
         'ACT3_BACDO' => 376,
         'ACT5_BACDO' => 376,
         'ACT1_BACDO' => 376,
         'ACT2_BACDO' => 376
       };
$VAR3589 = 'Caenorhabditis elegans.';
$VAR3590 = {
         'ACH5_CAEEL' => 511,
         '6PGD_CAEEL' => 484,
         'ACM2_CAEEL' => 627,
         'ACADM_CAEEL' => 417,
         'ADAL_CAEEL' => 388,
         'ACON_CAEEL' => 777,
         'ACBP3_CAEEL' => 116,
         '2AB1_CAEEL' => 495,
         '3HIDH_CAEEL' => 299,
         'ACH1_CAEEL' => 498,
         '6PGL_CAEEL' => 269,
         '2A51_CAEEL' => 542,
         '2AAA_CAEEL' => 590,
         'A16L2_CAEEL' => 534,
         'ACH4_CAEEL' => 548,
         'ACC2_CAEEL' => 445,
         'ADA17_CAEEL' => 686,
         'ACR5_CAEEL' => 598,
         'ACTL1_CAEEL' => 360,
         'ADBP1_CAEEL' => 217,
         'ACH8_CAEEL' => 474,
         '5NT3_CAEEL' => 376,
         'ACT2_CAEEL' => 376,
         'AAR2_CAEEL' => 357,
         'ACH23_CAEEL' => 545,
         'ACD11_CAEEL' => 617,
         'ABF2_CAEEL' => 85,
         'ABDH3_CAEEL' => 375,
         'ABF1_CAEEL' => 85,
         'ABH51_CAEEL' => 355,
         'ACX15_CAEEL' => 659,
         'ACC1_CAEEL' => 466,
         'ABL1_CAEEL' => 1224,
         'ACC3_CAEEL' => 517,
         'ABH52_CAEEL' => 444,
         'ACT4_CAEEL' => 376,
         'ACH2_CAEEL' => 493,
         'ACBP1_CAEEL' => 86,
         '14332_CAEEL' => 248,
         'ACR7_CAEEL' => 538,
         'ACC4_CAEEL' => 408,
         'ACE1_CAEEL' => 620,
         'AATC_CAEEL' => 408,
         'ACH6_CAEEL' => 502,
         'ACH3_CAEEL' => 564,
         'ACR3_CAEEL' => 487,
         'ACMSD_CAEEL' => 401,
         'ACH7_CAEEL' => 507,
         'ACR2_CAEEL' => 575,
         'ACASE_CAEEL' => 272,
         'ACM3_CAEEL' => 611,
         'AAPK2_CAEEL' => 626,
         'ACN1_CAEEL' => 906,
         '3HAO_CAEEL' => 281,
         'ADAS_CAEEL' => 597,
         'ACT1_CAEEL' => 376,
         'A4_CAEEL' => 686,
         'ADA10_CAEEL' => 922,
         'A16L1_CAEEL' => 578,
         'ACT3_CAEEL' => 376,
         'ACP1_CAEEL' => 426,
         'ACM1_CAEEL' => 713,
         'AAPK1_CAEEL' => 589,
         'ACOC_CAEEL' => 887,
         'ACLY_CAEEL' => 1106,
         '14331_CAEEL' => 248
       };
$VAR3591 = 'Anopheles stephensi (Indo-Pakistan malaria mosquito).';
$VAR3592 = {
         'ACES_ANOST' => 664
       };
$VAR3593 = 'Bacillus thuringiensis subsp. konkukian (strain 97-27).';
$VAR3594 = {
         'ACKA_BACHK' => 397,
         'ACCD_BACHK' => 289,
         'ACPS_BACHK' => 119,
         '3MGH_BACHK' => 205,
         'ACCA_BACHK' => 324,
         'ACP_BACHK' => 77
       };
```

More exactly, I wanto to know which organisms have more than 50 proteins Ids in my hash, and select them, getting rid of the other organisms with less number of proteins

Comment: Hash keys are by definition unique, what makes you expect otherwise?

Comment: Do you mean to say that an "organism" is a word which may be in various keys? (Like: an organism is `fly` and keys are `some fly`, `other fly` ...)  You never showed us the actual keys, but only an array with _words_ from all of them.

Comment: Can you show specific examples of an "_organism_" and multiple keys in which it is "_repeated_"?

Comment: Your code starts with `my @string = keys %hash;`. But since `%hash` cannot have duplicate keys by design (duplicate definition will overwrite the previous one) `@string` cannot have duplicate entries. Your code started with the wrong assumption. If you manually put duplicate entries into `@string` then it works.

Comment: But when I defined them as values, I still got no good results...

Comment: *"But when I defined them as values, I still got no good results."* - please provide the relevant code since it is not fully clear what you mean by this. In general please provide sufficient code so that others can reproduce your problem and not just the fragments you deem important.

Comment: @EmilioMármolSánchez: I assume that you've did `Dumper(%hash)` instead of `Dumper(\%hash)`. Still, it is not clear for me what you want to count. If it is the keys of the hash as asked in the title - there is exactly one of each by design. Substrings from the values of the inner hashes? Or what exactly? It might help to provide some realistic input and the expected output to better explain your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> More exactly, I wanto to know which organisms have more than 50 proteins Ids in my hash, and select them, getting rid of the other organisms with less number of proteins

I'm not fully sure that I've completely understood your question but it looks like you have the following kind of hash:

```
my %hash = (
    'protein_id#1' => {
         'some-number' => 'organism-name'
    },
    'protein_id#2' => {
         'some-number' => 'same-or-other-organism-name',
    },
    ...
);
```

And you want to count how many `protein_id#X´ are for each different`organism-name`.

In this case the following should work:

```
 my %organism;
 # "outer" hash has protein_id as key
 while (my ($protein,$h2) = each %hash) {
     # "inner" hash has organism-name as value
     # same organism could maybe be multiple times inside the same inner hash
     # but should only be counted once per protein_id
     my %organism;
     while (my ($some_number,$o) = each %$h2) {
         $organism{$o}++
     } 
     for (keys %organism) {
          $count{$_}++;
     }
 }
```

Comment: That provided the %count hash with the number of proteins for each organism yes, many thanks. But how to apply the %count values for each animal as a filtering procedure to only print the desired organisms with more than n (say 50) proteins? I have been wandering so long around this and could not reach a proper result... Something like, inside a foreach for running over the three dimensions of the hash, printing the keys (protID and number(length)) and the values (organism) if values of %count > 50.

Comment: @EmilioMármolSánchez: your original question asked for counting. Filtering based on the count is another question. But it could be done with doing similar construction of loops but this time not counting but instead deleting based on the previous count. Be aware though that you should not delete from a hash while iterating with `each` over it, i.e. either you collect the keys which need to be collected and delete after iteration or you iterate with `for (keys ...)` over the hash.